# Asignar un valor a una Caja de Texto ASP mediante JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Esta es mi función `JavaScript`:

```
function prueba() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var total = a + b;
    ('#TextBox1').val(total);
}
```

Este es el `.aspx`:

```
    <div>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

Y este el `aspx.cs`:

```
namespace widget
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel1, GetType(), "mifuncion", "prueba()", true);

        }


    }
}
```

Y quiero que se **asigne el valor de "total" en el Textbox**.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando JQuery te falta el $

```
function prueba() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var total = a + b;
    $('#TextBox1').val(total);
}
```

Comment: Ya se lo agregué, pero cuando ejecuto la app, el id del textBox, cambia de "TextBox1" a "MainContent_TextBox1", sabes a que se debe?

Comment: $('#MainContent_TextBox1').val(total);?

Comment: Sii, eso ya me salió, pero quisiera saber a que se debe que cambie el id?

Comment: .NET cambia los nombres de los elementos para "wire-up" al .cs. Lo que tienes que recordar es que Javascript funcciona en el browser entonces cuando vas a hacer cualquier cosa con javascript, revise el HTML en el browser (view source) o F12 tools

Comment: bueno entonces le dejaré ese ID

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Función JavaScript para asignar el valor al TextBox:

```
   function TuFuncionJS() {
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        var total = a + b;
        var valorTxt = document.getElementById("<%=Txt1.ClientID%>").value = total;
    }
```

En el CodeBehind si es que quieres que se asigne el texto al TextBox en el evento Load añades lo siguiente:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "TuFuncionJS();", true);
    }
```

En el aspx.cs:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda no dudes en preguntarme.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que estás usando Master Page; esto implica que cada ID que le pones del lado servidor, cuando se pinta en HTML se le agrega un ""MainContent_" al inicio del id porque es un segmento de html que estás incrustando en la página maestra.

Una opción es dejar el id completo como cuando se pinta "MainContent_Texbox1".

La segunda es, algo así:

```
$("#" + "<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").val(total);
```

[Información de la propiedad ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx)